# How do I average DateTime values in SQL Azure with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a SQL query that needs to average many datetime values server-side (in SQL Server). For example purposes, let's just consider it's a simple query like this on a table with millions of records:

```
SELECT
    SomeField,
    AVG(CAST(ADateTime AS decimal(18,8))) AS NumericRepresentation
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY SomeField
```

As shown, I can't simply take `AVG(ADateTime)` because SQL Server isn't happy with doing that, but converting it to a Decimal (and later converting it back to a DateTime) works well enough for me.

The obvious way to do something comparable with EntityFramework is to use `.Select(tbl => tbl.ADateTime.Ticks).Average()`, but this fails at runtime because `DateTime.Ticks` doesn't translate through Linq-to-Entities.

How should I best go about this? My main need is to average datetime values in some way. The temporary representation (decimals, ticks, etc) isn't terribly important as long as it can be translated back to a DateTime either in SQL or .NET code. What is important, though, is that the averaging is done in SQL Server (I have some fairly complex calculations with this over many records) and I can somehow have the translated DateTime in .NET (whether the translation happens in SQL Server or in .NET, I don't care).

Comment: What does `.Select(tbl => tbl.ADateTime).Average()` do? (I'm assuming it would create the above SQL statement without the cast, but Occam's Razor...)

Comment: @krillgar: It's a compile-time error. Average() is an extension method and there is no implementation that takes a DateTime. There are implementations that support decimal, double, float, etc. - the obvious stuff.

Comment: As I commented on [tgralex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57681072/1195056), the easiest solution would probably be to create a View or Stored Procedure to handle this for you in the database.

Comment: I only have read-only access to this database hosted/served by an outside company's service offering. Making changes is impossible for me as this is a standardize database for their SaaS product.

Comment: Gotcha. I've been there plenty of times before. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF LINQ expressions can make use of [SqlFunctions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions?view=netframework-4.8) class to make sure the conversion happens correctly.

```
DateTime minDate = new DateTime(1900,1,1);
var avg = MyTable.Select(myrow => SQLFunctions.DateDiff("second",myrow.ADateTime,minDate).Average();
DateTime avgDate = minDate.AddSeconds(avg);
```

---

#### Previous answer, should be disregarded:

Use `Convert.ToDouble`. <s>EntityFramework should be able to translate this</s> LINQ to SQL is able to `CONVERT(float,...)` **as long as your column is actually a `DateTime` and not `DateTime2` or `DateTimeOffset`,** but unfortunately Entity Framework is not able to recognize this construct.

```
.Select(tbl => Convert.ToDouble(tbl.ADateTime)).Average()
```

An alternate choice is to do it client side:

```
.Select(tbl => tbl.ADateTime).ToArray().Select(dt => dt.Ticks).Average()
```

though clearly that's not preferred if you're averaging millions of rows.

Comment: This is giving me the following exception: `System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Double ToDouble(System.DateTime)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.` I'm running EF 6.2.0 (targetframework=net46). Are there any additional requirements to get this to translate? FYI, my column is a `datetime` and not `datetime2` or any other flavor.

Comment: @Jaxidian That would tell me EF doesn't know what to do with it, so there wouldn't be "additional requirements" in the native code.

Comment: @Jaxidian Bummer. It worked with LINQ2SQL. I didn't have any EF handy unfortunately.  Would it be acceptable to use a [raw query](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/raw-sql-query-in-entity-framework.aspx)?

Comment: A variation of this is working for me. This has the unfortunate side-effect of only working with a fairly narrow date range of dates (you can only fit so many seconds into an Int32 and these do not work with Int64/bigints), but for my immediate need, this is sufficient. I'm sure I'll have a Y2035 bug or something at some point, but I can live with that in this system.

Answer (score 3):

In pure SQL you can do average on a date field with something like this:

```
-- the smallest date you could possibly have in your data
DECLARE @MinDate DATE = '1/1/1900' 
SELECT
    SomeField,
    DATEADD(DAY, AVG(DATEDIFF(DAY, @MinDate, ADateTime)), @MinDate) as AvgDateTime
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY SomeField
```

Not sure yet how to translate this to LINQ :)

**UPD:** Here is the LINQ code:

```
private static void Test(IQueryable<SomeClass> data)
    {
        var minDate = DateTime.MinValue;
        var avgMilliseconds = data.Select(x => x.SomeDateField.Subtract(minDate).TotalMilliseconds).Average();
        var avgDate = minDate.AddMilliseconds(avgMilliseconds);
        Console.WriteLine(avgMilliseconds);
        Console.WriteLine(avgDate);
    }
```

Comment: Worst case, a View could be created to retrieve this information given a dynamic `WHERE` clause.

Comment: You surely can create a view as well, but not sure why it is any worse than any other converting to double method.

Comment: LINQ 2 SQL doesn't understand `.Subtract(minDate)`. Are you positive EF does?

Comment: I didn't build a full example in my test app. I just confirmed LINQ is fine with above statement, compiles and runs correctly when I supplied data.AsQueryable(), where data is array. There is a possibility that LINQ 2SQL might not accept `.Subtract()` method, but don't know for sure. I guess it should be quite easy for the topic starter to check.

Comment: Since he accepted your answer I'll have to guess that it worked for him. However I wonder if you truly understand what a LINQ provider has to do to convert a tree of lambdas into SQL code. That process varies to a very, very large deal; the LINQ2SQL provider and the EntityFramework provider support very different edge cases.